# Angularjs: Get element in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs, I know that `$scope` represent a connection between the controller and the view, But is there a way besides looking for `class="ng-scope"` to get the scope element, I mean something like that:

```
function someControllerFunc($scope){
       $scope.element;
}
```

I know that same controller can be assigned to multiple scopes, So maybe it is not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by getting the scope element? Do you mean the element the controller is declared on?

Comment: You should never access any DOM elements from within the controller! This is exactly the type of behavior Angular is trying to discourage!!

Comment: Any sort of DOM interaction should be done only via directives, never in a controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get current scope dom-element in AngularJS controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960701/how-do-i-get-current-scope-dom-element-in-angularjs-controller)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can pass in the element to the controller, just like the scope:

```
function someControllerFunc($scope, $element){

}
```

Comment: Should i include any dependency in the module?, Because $element is undefined.

Comment: Actually, after more research, `$element` is not a good way to access the element, and is being [depricated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960701/how-do-i-get-current-scope-dom-element-in-angularjs-controller). You probably want to use a [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for this.

Comment: @apohl, where did you read that it's being deprecated? The link you provided doesn't say anything about that and I can't find anything in the documentation that says it's being deprecated...

Comment: @kentcdodds it explains it in the comments under the accepted answer.

Comment: @apohl, there's no mention of `$element` being deprecated in any of those comments... I need to know whether it's going to be deprecated because we use it in our app in several places, so I'd want to watch out for that when we upgrade....

Comment: @kentcdodds Ok, you're right. Deprecated was the wrong term. So that method will work, but it's not the suggested use.

Comment: @apohl -- Sometimes you can't help it, such in the case of a modal/popup scenario where you're essentially creating directives by hand using the `$compile` service to bind elements with controllers. I agree, it's a messy and non-elegant solution, but programming is full of those, right? =)

Comment: Is it poor too, if that controller used inside directive?

Answer (score 14):

`$element` is one of four locals that `$compileProvider` gives to `$controllerProvider` which then gets given to `$injector`. The injector injects locals in your controller function only if asked.

The four locals are:

- `$scope`
- `$element`
- `$attrs`
- `$transclude`

The official documentation: [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference - controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-)

The source code from [Github angular.js/compile.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L2113):

```
 function setupControllers($element, attrs, transcludeFn, controllerDirectives, isolateScope, scope) {
    var elementControllers = createMap();
    for (var controllerKey in controllerDirectives) {
      var directive = controllerDirectives[controllerKey];
      var locals = {
        $scope: directive === newIsolateScopeDirective || directive.$$isolateScope ? isolateScope : scope,
        $element: $element,
        $attrs: attrs,
        $transclude: transcludeFn
      };

      var controller = directive.controller;
      if (controller == '@') {
        controller = attrs[directive.name];
      }

      var controllerInstance = $controller(controller, locals, true, directive.controllerAs);
```

Answer (score 3):

I dont know what do you exactly mean but hope it help you.
by this directive you can access the DOM element inside controller
this is sample that help you to focus element inside controller

```
.directive('scopeElement', function () {
    return {
        restrict:"A", // E-Element A-Attribute C-Class M-Comments
        replace: false,
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
            $scope[attrs.scopeElement] = elem[0];
        }
    };
})
```

now, inside HTML

```
<input scope-element="txtMessage" >
```

then, inside controller :

```
.controller('messageController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.txtMessage.focus();
}])
```

Comment: I think you should have such functionality using a directive not element, check http://embed.plnkr.co/SgRVM6OIBOUV0hhia70X/, but still a good example to show how to get the element inside a controller

Answer (score 0):

Create custom directive

```
masterApp.directive('ngRenderCallback', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $scope[attrs.ngEl] = element[0];
                $scope.$eval(attrs.ngRenderCallback);               
            }, 30);
        }
    }
});
```

code for html template

```
<div ng-render-callback="fnRenderCarousel('carouselA')" ng-el="carouselA"></div>
```

function in controller

```
$scope.fnRenderCarousel = function(elName){
    $($scope[elName]).carousel();
}
```